# Export specific key from keychain using command line (by finger print, hash, id?)

Tags: keychain

I'd like to export specific keys from my keychain using the command line. As far as I see, this would involve the `security` tool. When I have multiple keys with the same name, how can I export a specific one of these keys? Can I specify a key id or hash value? For instance one can specify the type like `-t privKeys`, but this would not limit the result to a specific key.

Or going at this from a different angle: Is there a possibility in Keychain Access to view the key id / fingerprint of a key? For instance I have quite a few keys, which all are named the same and "Get Info" shows no details which would let me really distinguish one from another. I have a feeling I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to search by key identifier or hash.

Unfortunately the underlying [Keychain API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) is limited in the [attributes that can be searched](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/search_attribute_keys_and_values?language=objc) for.

If you are fortunate, paired certificate and keys exist within a Keychain. These pairings are called Identities within the API. Within Keychain Access they appear as a certificate with a disclosure triangle to one side; expanding the item reveals the paired key.

Otherwise applications working with Keychain have to enumerate the available certificates and keys to find specific pairs.

I wrote [Keysafe](https://miln.eu/keysafe/), so am painfully familiar with the underlying `.keychain` file format.